# When should I not use assignInNamespace?

Tags: r, namespaces

I have a use case, where I temporarily want to overwrite `package:::function()` for tests or because I will only use the function in a new way once.

I found `assignInNamespace` which does the job, e.g.

```
joke <- function(...) {return("hurz")}
assignInNamespace(x = "add1.glm", value = joke, pos = "package:stats")
stats:::add1.glm()
# [1] "hurz"
```

But the docs `??assignInNamespace` from package `utils` state

> Warning: assignInNamespace should not be used in final code, and will
>   in future throw an error if called from a package. **Already certain
>   uses are disallowed.**

Unfortunatelly, I can't find, what the warning really means, and it would be a waist of time, if this functionality `assignInNamespace` will be deprectaed completely in a while.
Did a miss any documentation?

---

**Edit**: I thought, that it will affect mostly my own packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unexported functions are functions that are not part of the public interface of a package. This means that the package makes no guarantees about

1. How this function gets called, and
2. Whether this function will still exist and be unchanged in future versions of the package.

This means that using such a function (including overriding it) will randomly break. That’s why its use in packages is forbidden: you *cannot* guarantee that it will continue to work.

That said, if you only use it for testing purposes under strictly controlled circumstances, the risk may be a valid trade-off. Even so, consider first whether there are less intrusive and brittle solutions.

Comment: So, in case of my own packages, it is save, and the function `assignInNamespace` won't be deprectaed? See my edit...

Comment: No, it's not safe in any code that you expect to use beyond the next patch release of R.

Comment: @user2554330 `assignInNamespace` will be deprecated?

Comment: @Christoph:  you're the one who posted the warnings from the docs about `assignInNamespace`.  But I was talking about the possibility that `stats:::add1.glm` will change.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this for testing purposes, you might be better off using `trace(stats:::add1.glm, edit = TRUE)`.  This will allow you to temporarily replace the body of the function with whatever code you want, and `untrace(stats::add1.glm)` will restore the original.  There's little chance that `trace()` will be deleted or drastically limited in the future.

You shouldn't try to do it in production code, for the reasons Konrad stated.

Comment: Cool option. I didn't know that.